# Iterating over reflected subclasses, variables don't appear to be shadowing, IntelliJ seems conflicted

Tags: java, inheritance, intellij-idea, reflection, shadowing

I'm working on a little Altair emulator in my free time.
I decided to try working in Java again after a VERY long time working with C#, so excuse any major idiocy on my part.

Essentially, I'm using a command pattern and org.reflections to make implementing machine instructions easy. Here's my reflection code.

```
        instructions = new ArrayList<IInstruction>();
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.cjm.eaglestar.instructions");

        Set<Class<? extends IInstruction>> subTypesOf = reflections.getSubTypesOf(IInstruction.class);
        for(Class<? extends IInstruction> command : subTypesOf){
            try {
                instructions.add(command.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Here's my interface for Instructions:

```
package com.cjm.eaglestar.instructions;

public interface IInstruction{
    byte OpCode = 0;
    String Mnemonic = "XXX";
    void Execute();
}
```

Here's a concrete implementation:

```
package com.cjm.eaglestar.instructions;

import static com.cjm.eaglestar.Eaglestar.machineState;

public class LDAInstruction implements IInstruction {
    public byte OpCode = Byte.valueOf("00111010",2);
    public String Mnemonic = "LDA";

    public void Execute(){
        machineState.programCounter++;
        byte lowByte = machineState.memory[machineState.programCounter & 0xFF];
        machineState.programCounter++;
        byte highByte = machineState.memory[machineState.programCounter & 0xFF];
        machineState.registers.A = machineState.memory[(lowByte & 0xFF) + ((highByte & 0xFF) * 256)];
    }

    public LDAInstruction(){
    }
}
```

Here's where things get weird. I use the OpCode to iterate over all the instructions, and when I come to compare the executing OpCode to the reflected instructions, **the comparison uses the superclass's default opcode (0), even though I'm not saying super.**

The effect in IntelliJ is even weirder. Mousing over shows the super opcode, but digging down into the instructions collection shows the correct concrete opcode. Here's some pictures of that weirdness.

[image: Superclass on mouseover]
[image: Subclass on drilldown]
Any help would be appreciated, as I'm just insanely lost and this is blocking any forward progress. Thanks.

EDIT: Just noticed in my screenshots that it says opcode = 0 (the user argument). Please ignore this. Usually it IS 58, I just skipped a step to get to the screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces do not have fields, the 'field' `IInstructions.OpCode` is a **constant** (implicit `public static final`), and while the `LDAInstruction.OpCode` is a field, that is irrelevant in the given code. With `IInstrunctions instructions`, the expression `instructions.OpCode` refers to the constant (be aware, it is considered a bad practice to refer to static members this way, and most IDEs and static analyzers will warn you about this).

This also explains the value shown by IntelliJ: in the loop, the code refers to `IInstructions.OpCode`, so it shows the value `0`, while inspecting the actual object, it knows it is an instance of `LDAInstruction`, which contains a field `opCode` with value `58`.

The rendering of the code by IntelliJ also gives a hint about this: the purple italic rendering is a static field, while the purple 'normal' (non-italic) rendering is an instance field.

You should **remove** `OpCode` from the interface, and instead declare a getter (`byte getOpCode()`, subclasses then need to implement that getter to return the right code for that instruction.

I also suggest that you acquaint yourself with Java naming conventions: a constant would be all uppercase (eg `OP_CODE`), while fields start with a lower case letter (eg `opCode`), fields are usually **not** `public`, and in this case it probably should be a final field so it can't be (accidentally or intentionally) modified.

You should also consider implementing this as an enum, as technically you only need a single instance of an instruction, eg

```
public enum Instruction {

    LDA(Byte.valueOf("00111010",2)) {
        @Override
        public void execute(MachineState machineState) {
            // your implementation.
        }
    },
    // other instructions
    ;    

    private final byte opCode;

    Instruction(byte opCode) {
        this.opCode = opcode;
    }

    public abstract void execute(MachineState machineState);

    public final byte getOpCode() {
        return opCode;
    }

}
```

In this case you could use the enum `name()` method instead of defining a separate mnemonic field + getter. And you can use the enum static method `valueOf(String)` to obtain instances by name.

But depending on the size of the execute implementations and the number of instructions, that may not be the best solution.

Another approach would be using to use an abstract class instead of (or in addition to) the interface, eg:

```
public abstract class AbstractInstruction {

   private final byte opCode;
   private final String mnemonic;

   protected AbstractInstruction(byte opCode, String mnemonic)  {
       this.opCode = opCode;
       this.mnemonic = mnemonic;
   }

   public abstract execute(MachineState machineState);

   public final byte getOpCode() {
       return opCode;
   }

   public final String getMnemonic() {
       return mnemonic;
   }
}
```

Comment: God. I can't believe I didn't think of this as a solution. I think I'm just used to being able to do this sort of thing in C# naturally. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mort432 A suggestion that I did not make explicit in my answer: in your code `machineState` seems to be a public static (final) field. You should really reconsider that design choice, and instead use an object that you pass to the `execute` method. That will make your code a lot clearer and prevents shared state if you ever want to be able to run multiple machines in parallel, it will likely also make state management for (unit) tests a lot easier

Comment: As a side note, instead of expensive constructs like `byte OpCode = Byte.valueOf("00111010",2);`, you can simply use `byte opCode = 0b00111010;`…